# Java 8 os.version does not contain entire Windows version

Tags: java

For Windows 10, Java 8 returns os.version=10.0 from System Properties, while the Windows 'ver' command returns 10.0.14393.

Is there any way to get the full windows version from java without running an external command?

Why is Java truncating the Windows version?

Comment: As always, “why did Java do this” can only be answered with opinions, unless people from the original Java design team want to answer.  Bear in mind that Java was conceived in the mid 90s, when the version reported by Windows was not as informative.  Changing the value of os.version would risk breaking older software that expected it in the original format.

Comment: I am wondering why do you need the minor version? What is the real purpose? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @notionquest trying to deal with specialized hardware errors due to windows bugs, and trying to use the build/patch version to detect when something is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, as ever, in the code - it's not that it's truncating it; it just never populates the build number.

Looking at the jdk8 source, they only populated [dwMajorVersion and dwMinorVersion](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c#l466):

```
sprintf(buf, "%d.%d", ver.dwMajorVersion, ver.dwMinorVersion);
sprops.os_version = _strdup(buf);
```

It's been this way since at least the [jdk6](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/ac1d168048bd/src/windows/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c#l802).

Now, if you want to get a full windows version, including the build, then you can [use JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) - the classes/interfaces you're looking for is `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT`, which contains the `VERSIONINFOEX` structure, and `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32` for the `GetVersionEx` function. I don't have a copy of windows to stub out the code for you; but it should be relatively easy to do (maybe something like this? I can't even try to test this out):

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Kernel32 kernel = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
    WinNT.OSVERSIONINFOEX vex = new WinNT.OSVERSIONINFOEX();
    if (kernel.GetVersionEx(vex)) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}.{1}.{2}",
            vex.dwMajorVersion.toString(),
            vex.dwMinorVersion.toString(),
            vex.dwBuildNumber.toString()));
    }
}
```

Asking for a rationale for this; it's pretty simple really - it never really mattered before windows 10 - you had strong delineations of behaviour based on the major and minor version of the OS; with the introduction of features by build for windows 10 it's complicated things.

Comment: good to see the edit - I was unable to test it and having the code work properly as an example is great for people.